# How To Fill Leftover Space

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting

I am making a fairly space intensive LaTeX "cheat sheet." Right now, I have added a single table, as so:

[image]

However, there is a large gap to the right of this table that I would like to fill with a few equations if possible. How would I go about doing this? I've seen other cheat sheet LaTeX examples, but they all had columns, which will not work for me because the various tables and equations lists will be of varying lengths and widths.

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\begin{document}

{\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{tabu}{|c | c | c| c| c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\bf \large Temperature Conversions} \\\hline

\bf  & \bf To K & \bf To C & \bf To F & \bf To R\\
\bf From K  &   --------    &   $C = K - 273.15$    &  $F = \frac{9}{5} K - 459.67$  &  $R = \frac{9}{5} K$ \\
\bf From C & $K = C + 273.15$ & -------- & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} $F = \frac{9}{5} C + 32$ & $R = \frac{9}{5} (C + 273.15)$\\
\bf From F & $K = \frac{5}{9} (F - 459.67)$ & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} $C = \frac{5}{9}(F - 32)$ & -------- & $R = F - 459.67$\\
\bf From R & $K = \frac{5}{9} R$ & $C = \frac{5}{9}(R - 491.67)$ & $F = R + 459.67$ & --------\\\hline
\end{tabu}
}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that `\minipage` is what you're looking for. Perhaps you should post a MWE for your table upon which people can build a full solution to your question.

Comment: But but but... we need the contents of TempConv.tex...

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Draksis Understood, but for the purpose of illustrating your problem, you need to give tex.stack.exchange users a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do. Adjusting `\thistablewidth` and the distance passed to `\vspace` may require some trial and error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\begin{document}
\newlength{\thistablewidth}
\setlength{\thistablewidth}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\thistablewidth}
\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{tabu}{|c | c | c| c| c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\bf \large Temperature Conversions} \\\hline

\bf  & \bf To K & \bf To C & \bf To F & \bf To R\\
\bf From K  &   --------    &   $C = K - 273.15$    &  $F = \frac{9}{5} K - 459.67$  &  $R = \frac{9}{5} K$ \\
\bf From C & $K = C + 273.15$ & -------- & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} $F = \frac{9}{5} C + 32$ & $R = \frac{9}{5} (C + 273.15)$\\
\bf From F & $K = \frac{5}{9} (F - 459.67)$ & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} $C = \frac{5}{9}(F - 32)$ & -------- & $R = F - 459.67$\\
\bf From R & $K = \frac{5}{9} R$ & $C = \frac{5}{9}(R - 491.67)$ & $F = R + 459.67$ & --------\\\hline
\end{tabu}   
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-\thistablewidth}
\vspace{-5em}
\begin{gather*}
a=b\\
b=c\\
c=a\\
e = mc^2\\
\omega^2 = gk \tanh {kh}
\end{gather*}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]